# YouTube volume is very low when played during a WebRTC session

Tags: youtube-api

I am working on an iOS app with WebRTC.  During the chat, volume is fine.  But if I play an embedded youtube video through WKYTPlayerView, volume of the video is very low.  If I disconnect the chat, video volume becomes normal again.

I have tried several things and I have been looking at this issue for few days.  Here is how I am setting the category for audio session;

```
NSError *error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
                                       error: &error];
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Problem setting AVAudioSession to mix with others");
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you figure out the solution? I have exact same issue and banging my head on the wall many days....

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are raised WebRTC issues. Here's 2 of them:

- [Low sound volume during calls](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=916)
- [AGC sets volume to zero](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=266048)

You may want to check the given fix which is putting up a CL to fix the problem in all platforms. See if it also works for you.

Otherwise, you can try using [mediastream-gain](https://github.com/otalk/mediastream-gain) which is useful for controlling rhe volume of your microphone input before it's sent accross a peer connection in a WebRTC call.

Lastly, you may want to also check this [thread](https://community.blackboard.com/thread/2719-my-students-cant-hear-the-audio-when-i-use-web-tour-or-application-sharing-to-play-youtube-videos) for additional insights on application sharing to play YouTube videos.

Comment: Thank for your response I appreciate the time you took to find these links.  Unfortunately, the CL wouldn't help me on the iOS device as iOS controls the volume based on the Category an app sets on AVAudioSession singleton.  The code I posted above is supposed to work but it is not for me.  I am trying to figure out if it is YTPlayer or WebRTC overriding the Category settings.

Comment: Also, I just want to make sure that t=my problem is explained clearly.  The audio for WebRTC session has no issues whether I play youtube video or not.  Only YouTube video volume is extremely low when WebRTC session is on.  I tried both YTPlayerView and WKYTPlayerView.